# How to move page and half-page in neovim (default key is not working for me)

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm a Neovim user

and I want to move by page for fast movement.

I found these commands, but for me only ctrl-u(half-page up) is working

[I reference this page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/All_the_right_moves)
Ctrl-D  move half-page down
Ctrl-U  move half-page up
Ctrl-B  page up
Ctrl-F  page down

**How can I figure out the problem?**

The problem is except ctrl-U, nothing works

**where can I check these default key map in my setting?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest starting your vim with no configuration to know if the problem is on vim or in your config files:

```
nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
```

Now test your shortcuts, if everything goes well try analyzing your settings

I also suggest a second test, try opening your vim in another terminal emulator, this issue can also be caused by your terminal. (These final paragraph was also in the comments and helped figuring out the problem)

Comment: I dont understand that snippet
should I add this snippet to my init.vim?
could you explain `-<character>`(seems like option) and `NONE`?

Comment: It will start your neovim with no configuration, just copy the suggested line, open a terminal and try running it.

Comment: thanks for tip, I try your command and like you said, it opened nvim with no-config, but ctrl-d, ctrl-b, ctrl-f is not working yet, then this means my default setting is wrong?
I have no idea to figure it out..

Comment: I suggest a second test, try opening your vim in another termial emulator, this issue can also be caused by your terminal.

Comment: yeah, you are right. iterm2 is not working but mac default terminal is working well.
Is there any ideas to figure out this difference?